# Apply CSS to particular component in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a personal portfolio using react which contain webpage I have created. I call those webpage as component in parent container. But the problem is each webpage have some conflicting class name. Due to which the corresponding styling properties are not applied.

What I want to ask is that...

Is there a way to apply a CSS file to a particular component only and not to any other components ?(something like scoping a CSS file to particular div)

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import Page1 from './Page1';
import Page2 from './Page2';

class WorksLarge extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="works">
          ///some code
        </div>
        <div className="works__preview">
          <Page2 /> //here I call the required Component
          <Page1 /> 
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default WorksLarge;
```

here is the component code

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import './page1.css';
import img1 from './img/page1-img-1.jpg';

class Page1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="body-container">
         ///Some code
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Page1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do using **@material-ui/styles** package. You can add CSS for particular components. Please check the attached code for my component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Snackbar, SnackbarContent, colors, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import CheckCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircleOutlined';
import CancelCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CancelOutlined';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  errorContent: {
    backgroundColor: colors.red[600]
  },
  successContent: {
    backgroundColor: colors.green[600]
  },
  message: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

const CustomSnackbar = props => {
  const { open, onClose, type, message} = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Snackbar
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'top',
        horizontal: 'center'
      }}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
      onClose={onClose}
      open={open}
      className={clsx(classes.Snackbar, 'Snackbar')}
    >
      <SnackbarContent
        className={clsx((type === 'Success' ? classes.successContent : classes.errorContent), 'msgContent')}
        message={
          <span className={clsx(classes.message, 'message')}>
            {type === 'Success' ? 
              <CheckCircleIcon className={clsx(classes.icon, 'icon')} />
              : 
              <CancelCircleIcon className={clsx(classes.icon, 'icon')} />
            }
              {message}
          </span>
        }
        action={[
          <IconButton key="close" aria-label="close" color="inherit" onClick={onClose}>
            <CloseIcon className={classes.closeIcon} />
          </IconButton>,
        ]}
        variant="elevation"
      />
    </Snackbar>
  );
};

CustomSnackbar.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

CustomSnackbar.defaultProps = {
  open: true,
  onClose: () => {},
  type: 'Success',
  message: 'Successfully saved changes!'
};

export default CustomSnackbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of achieving that, I like to use styled components, there are libraries for that, for example https://styled-components.com/ or Material UI styled components API (which I prefer) https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api

There are also other libraries like Emotion so you can choose one which you prefer.

You write CSS in JS in those libraries (mainly) which is little bit different in syntax than the regular CSS but is much more powerful so if you are not familiar with that I advice you to check that!

Example of the Material UI styled component (from their documentation):

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const MyButton = styled(Button)({
  background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
});

export default function StyledComponents() {
  return <MyButton>Styled Components</MyButton>;
}
```